# WP Не отображает шаблон для кастомного типа поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, создал произвольную таксономию `vendors` для неё создал кастомный тип записи постов `games` . Не могу понять почему не отображается шаблон записи.

```
//
///*
// *  Регистрация таксономии производителей
// */

add_action( 'init', 'create_vendor_taxonomies' );

// функция, создающая таксономии "vendors" для постов типа "vendor"
function create_vendor_taxonomies(){

    // Добавляем недревовидную таксономию 'vendors' (как метки)
    register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post', 'games'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Производители', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Поиск производителей' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Все производители' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Править производителя' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Обновить производителя' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Добавить нового производителя' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'Имя нового производителя' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
    ));
}

/*
 *  Тип записей для производителей Тип записи Game
 */

function create_games_posttype() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Games', 'Тип записей Games', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Game', 'Тип записей game', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Games', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Все игры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Обзор игры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить новую игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Добавить новую игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Редактировать игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Обновить игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Искать игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Не найдено', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'bahisyasal' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'games', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'description' => __( 'Каталог игр', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('vendors'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,

        'rewrite'   => array(
            'slug' => '/%vendors%',   // тип поста и сама таксономия
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-buddicons-activity',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'games', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_games_posttype', 0 );


/// Корректировка слага для games
add_filter('post_type_link', 'vendors_permalink', 1, 2 );
function vendors_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%vendors%' ) === false ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'vendors' );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    } else{
        $taxonomy_slug = 'no-vendors';
    }

    return str_replace( '%vendors%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал и `single-games.php` и `vendors-games.php`, но почему-то 404 страницу отдает. Если поменять постоянные ссылки на тип `%category%/%postname%` то `single-games.php` начинает работать, но тогда перестают работать `single.php` и `taxonomy-vendors.php`. Может кто-то посоветовать как решить проблему ?

Comment: Я сталкивался с подобным поведением wp, когда добавляешь кастомный посттайп, а он не работает. Мне помогало: Настройки->Постоянные ссылки->Сохранить изменения. (т.е ничего не изменял, просто зашел, нажал Сохранить изменения) И я бы попробовал закомментить код, отвечающий за корректировку слага для games, может в нем еще дело

Comment: "single-games.php начинает работать, но тогда перестают работать single.php". Не совсем понятно, что вы здесь имеете ввиду, Если вы находитесь на странице single-games, то логично что должен работать шаблон single-games.php ибо он перебивает single.php для страницы single-games (по иерархии шаблонов). У меня такое бывало, что перестает какой-то шаблон работать именно из-за моего непонимания иерархии шаблонов в wp. Т.е какой-шаблон в иерархии стоит выше, поэтому перебивает.

Comment: single.php у меня выводит посты новостей (стандартный шаблон). При подключении данного кода в function.php на страницы новостей оно перестает заходить, если прописать `%category%/%postname%`

Comment: вот эта строчка смущает: `register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post', 'games'), array(` Т.е вы регистрируете таксономию с названием vendors, ок, но зачем этот массив `array('vendor', 'post', 'games')` Я бы так переписал эту строчку: (с учетом того, что создается таксономия для кастомного посттайпа games) `register_taxonomy( 'vendors', [ 'games' ], [`

Comment: `array('vendor', 'post', 'games')` Извиняюсь, я понял, вы хотите добавить этой строчкой таксономию для обычных постов WordPress и еще кастомного посттайпа vendor. Но даже с учетом этого, причина где-то здесь может быть. Попробуйте для начала оставить только games, даст ли это что-то.

Comment: Еще момент: вот здесь https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy среди прочего указано, что "Сначала нужно регистрировать таксономию, а потом тип записи с которым эта таксономия связана. Эта особенность в некоторых случаях избавит вас от багов и кучи потраченного времени." А у вас таксономия сразу для 3-ех посттайпов, среди которых один так вообще стандартный вордпрессовский.